# Event handler in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery in my application of Form Buildr
I have used the Clean calendar.js file and it works fine.
 Like when i click on a textbox of class CalendarSelectDate it will popup a calendar and i can choose the date value and the selected value will appear on the Textbox..

I am trying to get the changed value of the Textbox.. I do not know what event it is ..And how to get that selected date..

Please suggest me...

My code is

```
  <input type="text" value="" style="width: 200px;" 
     class="calendarSelectDate" id="5" name="data[Result][Untitled Date 1]"/>
 <div id="calendarDiv"> //this is where my calendar pops up.
```

and using the plugin 
http://marcgrabanski.com/pages/code/clean-calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [jQuery's UI Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#events) you can bind something to the onSelect event:

```
$('.calendarSelectDate').datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

If it's some other plugin, you can simply use the [change event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change):

```
$('.calendarSelectDate').somedatepicker().change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Actually i m using the Clean calendar of
http://marcgrabanski.com/pages/code/clean-calendar